# Rgd: PHP-FPM Installation

Tags: centos, php, php-fpm

Rgd: PHP-FPM Installation

I used to install PHP-FPM by this ways..

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm
```

But now i try the same way, it give me php-fpm package not found.

I am running CentOS 6 with php 5.3.26(cli) installed.

I am trying install php-fpm and then do a service php-fpm start which I did for my other server but today I try install the same thing using the same steps it does not work..

Anyone can guide me on how to get php-fpm setup on my this new server

Answer (score 0):

Since CentOS 6.4 is PHP-FPM included in their php builds.

You can try :

```
rpm --import http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

yum install yum-priorities
```

and edit:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

and set:

```
enabled=1
priority=10
```

Let me know if it worked out for you!